# Why does this js if clause not stop looping?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, setinterval

The following is supposed to check a page for data (a simple integer) every 10 seconds.  When the integer exists (data != null), then alert and stop the interval for good).

**BUT**
Instead it queues up alerts, every 10 seconds.  And when the script finally does find the integer it's looking for, a flood of alerts pops up... one for every ten seconds.  If the script lasts 50 seconds, you'll get 5 alerts all at once 50 seconds after the page loads.

What's the problem?  Shouldn't the `if (data != null) {` prevent the alert from triggering at all... until there's data?  I'm at a loss.  Plus, "data" never shows up in the alert.

```
var pinger;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pinger = setInterval(function(){
        $.get("/ajax.php", function(data) {
            if (data != null) {     /** Shouldn't this line stop loops? **/
                alert("alert" + data);
                clearInterval(pinger);
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: You are defining your pinger variable twice. Have you tried omitting the first (global) declaration?

Comment: I had read earlier to do that in order for the clearInterval to work. But I had bigger problems...  The setTimeout is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/ajax.php` takes more time than the delay at which setInterval() calls your function. So when it ends, setInterval() had actually called the function multiple times.

Use setTimeout() instead of setInterval():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function self(){
        $.get("/ajax.php", function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                alert("alert" + data);
            } else {
                setTimeout(self, 10000);
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: So good.  Thanks so much.  The script works *almost* perfectly now.  But, I used: `alert("text" + data + "text");` and the output is "texttext" when it should be "text12345text".  Is the data itself not passed down?

Comment: this means you ajax.php script returned an empty string

Comment: ha, just replace alert("alert" + text); by alert("alert" + data);

Comment: You were correct the first time... my ajax.php was messed up too. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you don't get a null from `$.get` (even if there's an empty string then comparing it to null returns true - `'' != null` return true). That's why the alerts are poping-up.

Also, some made a good point, that if your ajax call takes more than a 10 seconds it would fire another time, even though previous ajax might return correct data that suppose to stop the loop.